# View Shows Latest Members - How to Limit Count by Last 3 Months

Tags: views, users

I created a view that shows all recent members. Right now it shows members, from the newest to the oldest. I want to limit this view to show only the last 3 months of latest users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your views 'Filter criteria' add another filter and choose 'User: Created date' and choose an operator which suit your needs, An example shown below. It will list users that are created between last 90 days

[image]